# How to remove data from mongodb collection using nodejs and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a problem removing data in my Nodejs app. I have 2 buttons in my ejs template that send the exactly same URL to server to remove 2 models:
the first button:

```
<td class="td6"><a href="/myprojects/<%= project._id %>/cost/<%= labour._id %>/remove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button></a></td>
```

The second button:

```
<td class="td21"><a href="/myprojects/<%= project._id %>/cost/<%= tool._id %>/remove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button></a></td>
```

I also have exactly the same route for both for removing data. The first one working perfectly but the second one doesn't work at all:

first route:

```
app.get("/myprojects/:id/cost/:labour_id/remove", function(req, res){
Labour.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.labour_id, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        }else{
            Project.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundProject){
                if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                        }else{
                        res.redirect("/myprojects/" +req.params.id+ "/cost");
                        }
            });
    }
});

});
```

and the second route:

```
app.get("/myprojects/:id/cost/:tool_id/remove", function(req, res){
Tool.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.tool_id, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        }else{
            Project.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundProject){
                if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                        }else{
                        res.redirect("/myprojects/" +req.params.id+ "/cost");
                        }
            });
    }
});

});
```

can anyone see any problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to use the exact same route pattern for doing two different things (or, well, exactly same thing, but on different kinds of entities). What I mean is that for Express `/myprojects/:id/cost/:labour_id/remove` and `/myprojects/:id/cost/:tool_id/remove` are exactly same routes, so the second one simply never gets matched. The solution would be to make two different routes like `/myprojects/:id/costs/labors/:labour_id/remove` and `/myprojects/:id/costs/tools/:tool_id/remove` respectively (note `/labors/` and `/tools/` sections).

Another way (and that's what you were probably trying to do) would be to create a universal route like `/myprojects/:id/costs/:entity(labours|tools)/:tool_id/remove` and use corresponding Mongoose model based on the value of the `entity` parameter. However, I wouldn't recommend it, since it would make the code way less readable. Sometimes duplication is not such a bad thing. ;)

Also, as a general rule, it's a good practice to implement removal routes as methods `delete` methods (`app.delete`).

Comment: I tried the first option and worked perfect. Thanks for your good answer